# How to check what is blocked through Content-Security-Policy?

Tags: html, http, header, w3c, content-security-policy

I tried to set the following Content-Security-Policy header for my website:

```
header('Content-Security-Policy: "default-src \'none\'; script-src \'self\'; connect-src \'self\'; img-src * data:; style-src \'self\';"');
```

But the result was in some parts strange. For example this `<table>`:
[image]

became this:
[image]

As styles work I tried to find out through Google Chrome Developer Tools which content was blocked, but I had no success to find error messages or similar.

How can I find out what caused this style change?

Partial code of this table:

```
<table id=threads cellspacing=1>
    <col />
    <col style="width:66%" />
    <col style="width:8%" />
    <col style="width:26%" />
    <tr>
        <th colspan=2>&Auml;hnliche Beitr&auml;ge</th>
        <th>Re:<br />&#8730;</th>
        <th>Letzter&nbsp;Beitrag</th>
    </tr>
    <tr onmouseover="this.className='even'" onmouseout="this.className=''">
    ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to allow inline styles, the only way is with `style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'`.

**But  if you use `'unsafe-inline'`, you may as well not use CSP at all; it’s an unsafe policy.**

Inline styles are only allowed if the CSP header explicitly includes `'unsafe-inline'` for them.

Your CSP header lacks `'unsafe-inline'`, so all your `style="width:66%"`, etc., are not applied.

---

As far as getting more detailed info back to pinpoint exactly what styles have been blocked, there’s not a way. Even if you use the [`report-ui` directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/report-uri), you’ll only get back the same level of detail you get back from your browser — that is, just a report saying  you have a document that’s using inline styles, with only the same level of detail as this browser message:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-style 'self'"

Comment: Ok, thank you. This solves my problem, but does not answer my question. What if I find an additional problem, is there no way to see in the browser which content was blocked?

Comment: See my updated answer. I think for instances of inline style or script, there’s no way to get more-detailed information back about exactly what was blocked. Instead you just get a message saying a document contained inline style/script and so it was blocked

Comment: Sad that it does not contain more details, but its ok to find attacks and unwanted blocked content. For example I found blocked iframes with youtube.com as source because users are allowed to post videos. And this could be solved by adding `child-src 'self' https://www.youtube.com;`.